# MacBook Pro's Right Click / Secondary Tap is Switching Programs

Tags: mac, touchpad, right-click

A family member's MacBook Pro seems to have the "Secondary Tap" action mapped to program switching instead of popping up the context menu.  This happens when a mouse is plugged in as well as when two-finger tapping the trackpad.

No preferences related to what the right mouse button should do come up when looking at the mouse preferences.

Googling so far makes it look like a Magic and/or Mighty Mouse could have caused some of these weird issues if it was plugged in at some point but we don't have one available now.  I have not been able to figure out if these prefs actually exists on the machine and, if they do exists, how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a third-party mouse driver or manager prefpane installed that allows remapping the mouse buttons.

[USBOverdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) or one of [these](http://alternativeto.net/software/usboverdrive/) are some of the possibilities.

Comment: None of those are installed :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JRobert. It sounds like a third-party mouse driver/manager.

I noticed BetterTouchTools, magicprefs and jitouch were not on his list. Make sure those are not installed either.